# What constitutes an axiom - Spivak Calculus ch. 1

Tags: axioms

In chapter 1 of Spivak's Calculus text he lays out some fundamental axioms of the integers. For instance that: $a \cdot 1 = a$, for all $a$. However he doesn't list an axiom that for instance says: $a \cdot 0 = 0$, for all $a$. This seems a bit arbitrary. Can we derive $a \cdot 0 = 0$ from Spivak's other axioms? On page $6$ he just says that $a \cdot 0 = 0$, for all $a$, without explanation.

Also he seems to be taking for granted that if $a = b$, then $a + c = b + c$. Another implicit axiom.

Why doesn't he mention these *“implicit axioms”* explicitly?

Comment: Your "if a + b, then a + c = b + c" is part of the definition of "operator". I agree that it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Actually, it's part of what constitutes *identity*. Whenever $a=b$, we also have $\phi(a)\leftrightarrow\phi(b)$ for all predicates $\phi$. If we take $\phi(x)\equiv x+c=a+c$ then this means $a+c=a+c\leftrightarrow b+c=a+c$. And $a+c=a+c$ is of course also true )by refelxivity of $=$). Such is sometimes taken for granted ("FOL with identity")

Comment: I'd note that Spivak does actually give an explanation of a * 0 = 0 on the next page. Sorry about that

Answer (score 10):

First of all, if one is describing the integers axiomatically, the axiom is **not** that "$a\cdot 1=a$ for all $a$", but rather that there **exists** a number "$1$" that has that property (one can then proceed to prove that it must be the *only* number with that property).

Similarly, the corresponding axiom for addition is that there exists some number "$0$" with the property that $a+0=a$ for any $a$.

However, looking in the book, I can see that Spivak is listing *properties* of the integers, some phrased as axioms, but he is taking the integers as already having been constructed, so that he doesn't need to say things in the way I did above. For example, he says

> [image]

At any rate, to answer your first question, by the axiom that multiplication distributes over addition, we know that for any $a$ we have
$$a\cdot (0+0)=a\cdot 0+a\cdot 0$$
But $0+0=0$ because $0$ (by definition) is an additive identity, so 
$$a\cdot 0=a\cdot 0+a\cdot 0$$
Whatever $a\cdot 0$ is, we know it has an additive inverse, which we can now add to both sides:
$$(a\cdot 0)+(-(a\cdot 0))=(a\cdot 0)+(a\cdot 0)+(-(a\cdot 0))$$
$$0=(a\cdot 0)+0$$
$$0=a\cdot 0$$
Also, the statement that $a=b$ means that they are *identical*, that there is a single number that we have given two different names to. Any expression whatsoever involving $a$ can have $b$ substitued for $a$ in it, and vice versa. That is simply what equality *means* - there is no unstated axiom.

Comment: Are you saying that: if a = b, then a + c = b + c; is not an axiom in the same sense that 1 + 1 = 2 is not an axiom?

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree with the first two sentences.  It seems like the language in which the axioms are stated might have constant symbols for 0 and 1.

Answer (score 4):

There is a standard proof that $a\cdot 0=0$. Notice that $a\cdot (0)=a\cdot (0+0)=a\cdot (0)+a\cdot (0)$. Subtracting the left hand side from the right-hand side gives the desired result.

The other result depends on the other axioms used.

Answer (score 0):

I have not read Spivak, but I imagine the axioms of the integers he refers to are just the axioms of a commutative ring. If you look over all of these, I think you'll see why each is necessary. He probably writes $a + 0 = a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. This is the definition of $0$. He also probably writes $a + (-a) = 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. This is the definition of $-a$. I imagine he also talks about distributivity, commutativity, and associativity. From all these things, we get all of what we want.

The reason why $a \cdot 0 = 0$ has been mentioned in the other posts. One would first give the set theoretic construction of $\mathbb{Z}$ to prove that if $a=b$ then $a+c=b+c$ for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The answer to the questions you ask really just come over time, and at some point it just "clicks".